# Exit Python while loop with error

Tags: python

I have a while loop that I've set up in python and I want it to raise an error if the timer runs our or one of my variables evaluates to false.  How do I do this? I've tried `raise` but that didn't work.

Here's the code:

```
timeout = time.time() + 60 #60 second timer
if os.environ.get("Continue") == None:
  while True:
    print "waiting..."
    if Keep_Going == "False" or time.time() > timeout: #Keep_Going is a user input
        print "Quiting"
        raise Exception('Quiting') #I want the loop to raise and error and stop my code here
    if os.environ.get("Continue") == "True":
        break #continue with next code block if this happens.
```

Comment: what is `os.environ.get("Continue")  == "False"` doing?

Comment: "I've tried raise but that didn't work." is not a good problem description. What do you want to do, what is expected behavior and how your current behavior differs from expected one?

Comment: The example, as written, does not run. If possible, please provide a complete, minimal, runnable example that demonstrates the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Did you see "waiting" in console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to exit with an error message you can always use :

```
import sys
sys.exit("Your error message")
```

Answer (score 2):

You are checking an environment variable for your condition.

This leads me to believe that you think you can alter that environment variable from somewhere else (like another shell, etc) and see the changes here in your program.

That is not the case (:

Once a program runs, it gets a copy of the environment. Any changes made externally are not seen in the copy. Any changes in the copy are not seen externally.

If you explain more exactly what you are trying to do, perhaps we can provide a more thorough answer.

Comment: I have a web application I want to use this with.  The application looks for an error flag and if it get's one then this loop is triggered.  I want the loop to wait for the users input (`Continue == "False" or "True"`) and then raise an exception if Continue is false, or keep going if it is true.

Comment: Ok, but inside that loop, nothing is going to be changing environment variable values (inside `os.environ`), so checking for change there is strange... I am probably not understanding everything, though.